# How can I fix HttpListenerException: Invalid network name format in SignalR server app?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, server, signalr

SignalR in .NET Console Application. HttpListenerException: Invalid network name format

Hello! I do tried everything I could. Here my full server code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://myip:8080";
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server SignalR is started: " + url);

                AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                waitHandle.WaitOne();
            }

        }

        public class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                var config = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                    EnableJavaScriptProxies = false,
                    EnableJSONP = true
                };
                app.MapSignalR(config);
            }
        }

        public class ChatHub : Hub
        {
            public void SendMessage(string message)
            {
                Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This port and ip is work in my WCF server application with no problem. Exception occurs in stroke:

```
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
```

With localhost this app work normally. I tried to download different package versions of Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR and Microsoft.Owin. Uselessly...